# Is FirstOrDefault() method good way to handle this scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have class `Group` which contains list of users that are members of group.
I use `FirstOrDefault()` method to check if user that open group page is already in that group.
Based on that I display 'Join Group' or 'Leave Group' button.
I just wonder if this is the good method for scenario like this or there is better way?

```
public class Group
{
    public virtual ICollection<UserInGroup> UsersInGroups { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In details action method I first load group and then check is user in group:

```
public ActionResult Show(int groupId, string title)
{
    GroupViewModel groupiewModel = new GroupViewModel();

    var model = groupsRepository.GetGroupById(groupId);

    groupiewModel.Group = model;

    Guid userId = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
    var alreadyInGroup = model.UsersInGroups.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);

    if (alreadyInGroup != null)
        groupiewModel.IsInThisGroup = true;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think `Any` is a better choice

```
bool alreadyInGroup = model.UsersInGroups.Any(x => x.UserId == userId); 

if (alreadyInGroup)
{
     ....
```

Comment: True, yet this method will download all data from the database server. This should be avoided.

Comment: Note the Entity Framework tags.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying this for that reason. See my answer. model.UsersInGroups is not an IQueryable.

Comment: @usr what will I get if I change IEnumerable to IQueriable?

Comment: @1110 please see my answer. Currently you have a problem in that UsersInGroups might contain 1000s of users which will all be fetched from the database. This is a huge performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using Any rather than FirstOrDefault means than you don't waste time on creating an instance.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you wish to execute the filter condition on the database server. You are invoking `FirstOrDefault` on an `IEnumerable` which means you are downloading *all* users and filtering in memory.

So this is not the right way to do it.

Instead, build a LINQ query and execute that.

On that occasion you can switch to `Any`.